# add times from strings to get hours [php]

Tags: php

I inherited an pretty old project for business-times.
Right now I'm struggling to determine the sum of all given "strings"

For example, I have something like this:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> string(8) "04:19:24"
    [1]=> string(8) "04:32:03"
    [2]=> string(8) "04:17:20"
}
```

The whole thing is **completly procedural**, no classes or anything OOP-related. Now I'm stuck with adding those times together.

I found several functions like `gmdate`, `mktime`, `strtotime` ... but it seems like it isn't the right.

I also tried to convert them to DateTime-objects to add them, but then I ended up with days (for example 1 day, 2 hours ...).
What I actually need is something like: **40:21:31**

I thought about creating timestamps from that as well (or atleast calculate them down to seconds, add those and make a small calculation afterwards to get back to this pattern), but I didn't find a function which is able of it.

**edit 1:**

Well, I don't know if that is the best way to do it, but since I can rely on the syntax, I'm going to `explode` these strings into an array and do some simple math:

```
$aPieces = explode(":", "04:19:12");
$iSecsFromHours = $aPieces[0]*60*60;
$iSecsFromMinutes = $aPieces[1]*60;
$iTotal = $iSecsFromHours + $iSecsFromMinutes + $aPieces[2];
```

With that, I can get a sum of all seconds, but that still leaves open the point on how get a format like **HH:MM:SS** (`gmdate` works only for < 1 day).

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer now, taken from [here](http://codeaid.net/php/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds-(php)):

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    // extract hours
    $hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));

    // extract minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $seconds % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    // extract the remaining seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    // return the final array
    $obj = array(
        "h" => (int) $hours,
        "m" => (int) $minutes,
        "s" => (int) $seconds,
    );
    return $obj;
}
```